# Build option is not shown in iTunes connect when we try to submit our app

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

In iTunes connect i had done almost all steps to publish the app,but at last the + sign and build option is not shown when i am trying to submit my app.I had followed this link from youtube . 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnbOcpwJGa8

What to do?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CDJJ.png)

Comment: when you upload build at iTunes?

Comment: either your bundle identifier or app name is not not same.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sign in to your account : https://itunesconnect.apple.com/
Click on **My apps** -> **your Project** ->**Activity tab**.
In Activity tab, you should check you app version that you uploaded is there or not.
if **not** then you have to upload that build again.Use Application Loader to upload your build


if **yes** then check the status of the build. if status of your build is in **processing** then you have wait for that. When processing get completed by apple , you can see the + option in build.

If you having doubt than comment below.

Thank you.
```